rke2-ingress-nginx missing master node's ip adress
My cluster was fine for like 40 days without problem. But today it suddenly broken. When i curl to my app with command:
curl 10.20.30.80 output: connection refused.
I checked my ingress and realised that my master node ip is not listed in ingress Address.

I tried restarting nodes.

My Nodes
kube-system pods
My Ingress
